# Connection refused when golang app tries to connect to postgresql in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a golang app and a postgres server inside a docker-compose file.

Bu it returns the following error in the golang app:

```
2023/12/16 17:57:44 Connecting to postgres database postgres://dev:passwordqwerty@dborder:5432/orderdb?sslmode=disable
2023/12/16 17:57:44 Failed to connect to database

2023/12/16 17:57:44 /build/db/db.go:28
[error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=dborder user=dev database=orderdb`: dial error (dial tcp 172.19.0.2:5432: connect: connection refused)
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: order-api
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_URL: postgres://dev:passwordqwerty@dborder:5432/orderdb?sslmode=disable
      DB_DRIVER: postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    container_name: dborder
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: always
    hostname: dborder
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passwordqwerty
      POSTGRES_DB: orderdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - mynet

volumes:
  postgresql:

networks:
  mynet:
    name: mynet-network
    driver: bridge
```

I tried to specify the hostname but no success at all.

Comment: If you try to connect immediately when your web container starts, the database might not be ready. It takes a bit of time for postgres to get ready to accept connections and `depends_on` only waits for the database container to be started - not ready.

Comment: If @HansKilian's diagnosis is correct, also see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).  Go containers tend to start up very quickly and are a little more prone to this problem than less-efficient interpreted languages.

Comment: (To simplify this setup, also consider removing all of the `networks:`, `container_name:`, and `hostname:` settings, and using the Compose service name `db` as the host name in `$DB_URL`.  Compose provides reasonable defaults for all of these settings.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help! I've finally solved my problem!

Indeed it was because golang apps tend to start up so fast even before the database container become ready and healthy.

I only needeed to add the `helthcheck` property in the `db` service end modify a little bit the `depends_on` value.

The new `docker-compose` after the adjustments:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    container_name: order-api
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_URL: "postgres://dev:passwordqwerty@dborder:5432/orderdb?sslmode=disable"
      DB_DRIVER: postgres
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mynet

  db:
    container_name: dborder
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0" # -> any healthcheck will works
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dev
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: passwordqwerty
      POSTGRES_DB: orderdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - mynet

volumes:
  postgresql:

networks:
  mynet:
    name: mynet-network
    driver: bridge
```

Probably this file can still be simplyfied, but for now, it is Ok for me...